# preg_replace displaying with limit?

Tags: php, function, preg-replace

I have php code

```
preg_replace( "/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/", 
               "$1 $2 $3 $4", 
               121234123412341234)
```

The result of this is `1.21234123412E+17`. I need to be `12 1234 1234....`

Maybe i need to use other function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quote around input

```
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})/", "$1 $2 $3 $4", '121234123412341234');
```

**Output**

```
12 1234 1234 12341234
```

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/9cmjGFdJ)

Comment: Was my first intention too, `strval` is also a suitable solution for variables

Comment: @Joshua - How exactly is `strval()` a solution? If PHP cannot store a very large integer, there's no way to get to it back by converting it to string—the value is gone by then.

Answer (score 0):

Use strings. PHP [cannot handle such large integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) unless they get converted to float:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value
>   of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed).
>   64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does
>   not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using
>   the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant
>   PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

In my computer, `PHP_INT_MAX` is 2147483647.

To sum up, please compare:

```
var_dump(121234123412341234, '121234123412341234');
```

```
float(1.2123412341234E+17)
string(18) "121234123412341234"
```